# Reset a single user registry to defaults

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry

I have a limited user on a home computer that managed to mess up his settings and I want to reset that user to defaults.

In Windows XP I could delete ntuser.dat and the registry to reconstructed properly.  On Win7 the user gets logged on with a temporary profile.    I also tried copying ntuser.dat from c:\users\default.  This prevents the user from loggin in.

Comment: Delete the user account completely, and recreate it. That will reset it to defaults.

Comment: If I delete and recreate the account the user will lose access and ownership of files and doucments created by the old user.,

Comment: For all the bother it might be, it'll still be quicker to re-assign permissions than the 14 hours you've waited for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

you also have to delete the UserProleList entry from the registry.
Naviage to: "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList"
and find the right profile entry.
(Always backup the registry before!)